# Is there a way to know Twilio's queue status?

Tags: node.js, queue, twilio

I'm trying to delay the sending rate from my app and I need to know exactly how full is the queue at this time. Right now I'm waiting until I get a queue is full (status:429) code in order to delay the current sending rate.

Comment: Can you provide more details here. Are you talking SMS? Voice? 429's are usually when you are sending to many concurrent API requests and how to handle is covered here - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044308153-Twilio-API-response-Error-429-Too-Many-Requests-

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about SMS. Just want to know how full the queue is. And once I get the information I may start delaying the sending rate according to that information (for example when the queue is  60% full)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually recommend that you respond to 429 responses in the way that you describe. Once you receive a 429 you should back off and retry until you receive 200 responses again. I don't think there's a benefit in backing off before you reach the limit. It's definitely recommended that you implement back offs and retries like this as there may be other reasons that you receive a 429 response that isn't a full queue (like too many concurrent connections).

On the other hand, we don't have an API or way to get the current queue length. But, if you do want at least an estimate of current queue length, we do have this blog post which gives you a method of [calculating the current queue length based on the number of requests you have made, the number of message segments you are trying to send and the throughput](https://www.twilio.com/blog/calculate-message-queue-length).

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. You've answered my questions and thank you for the link!

Comment: Fantastic, if it did answer the question for you, please do mark it as correct so that others can see it helped too. Thanks!